# Limiting number of text lines in a table cell

Tags: html, css

I have a table cell where I need to limit the text to a max of two lines.
I tried achieving this by placing an inner div with a limited height:

```
div 
{ 
  border: 1px solid #EECCDD;  
  width: 100px;
  height: 40px; 
  overflow: hidden; 
}

<div>
   <p>bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla</p>
</div>
<div>
   <p>bla bla bla bla</p>
</div>
```

However, in this case the cells which have only one line of text are not vertically aligned to the middle. I know there are ways to vertically align a text within a div, but most of the ones I found seemed a bit complicated and/or hacky (like [this one](http://www.jakpsatweb.cz/css/css-vertical-center-solution.html)), and felt like a bit of an overkill.

Is there a different way to effectively limit the number of lines inside the cell, or a simple way to align the text in the way I did it?

Comment: What happens if you set a max-height: 40px instead of height: 40px

Comment: Two things - 1) it works 2) I feel like I really should have seen it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this :

```
 div 
{ 
  border: 1px solid #EECCDD;  
  width: 100px;
  height: auto; 
  max-height: 40px;
  overflow: hidden; 
}
```

instead of this :

```
 div 
{ 
  border: 1px solid #EECCDD;  
  width: 100px;
  height: 40px;
  overflow: hidden; 
}
```

Comment: No need for the height:auto, changing the height to max-height was enough.

Comment: ok, see the second answer maybe it can help you with vertical align

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery for this. Example:

**html**

```
<div><span class="text">text goes here <br /></span></div>
```

**jQuery**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    var div = $("div");
    var divText = $(".text");
    var divTextTop;
    divTextTop = ( div.height() / 2 ) - ( divText.height() / 2 );
    divText.css({
    'position' : 'relative',
    'top': divTextTop + 'px',
    'color': '#555'
    });
  });
</script>
```

I hope this code will help you with vertical alignment; the code is very simple.